# Issues placing P tag below H1

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I've had this issue across multiple sites and have never been able to fix it. The issue is, I have an h1 tag inside a container that is aligned vertically using align-items. Below that h1 I want to place a p tag. This is probably an easy fix yet I've never been able to solve this issue.

I've tried using line-height instead of align-items or creating a new container for the p tag, I also tried removing the bottom margin from the h1 and the top from the p tag but nothing has worked. What's the solution here?

```css
.headertext {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.header {
  background-image: url('1080background.png');
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  display: inline;
}

p {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="headertext">
    <h1>Jude Wallach</h1>
    <p>Test</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Site](https://1080benchmarks.github.io/projects/legit/index.html) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On solution there is to add `flex-flow: column;` to your `.headertext` class

Answer (score 0):

Just add `flex-direction: column` to your `. headertext` CSS. The default flex aligns flex items horizontally, `flex-direction: column`  vertically.

BTW: `display: inline` on the `h1`isn't really helpful - just rease it